# Logging into Wordpress

Tags: c#, wordpress

I am attempting to make a program that automatically downloads some files from a Wordpress site but the problem is you have to be authenticated to download them. I have looked around but can't find anything that will really help me understand this.

This is the code that does the logging in but from what I am gathering it is not storing all the needed cookies for Wordpress, but I haven't found many examples regarding this.

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("https://www.gplvault.com/wp-admin");
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer, AllowAutoRedirect = false})
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler, false) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "https://www.gplvault.com/my-account/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");

    var homePageResult = client.GetAsync("/");
    Console.WriteLine("1: " + cookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(baseAddress));
    homePageResult.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]{
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
    });
    var loginResult = client.PostAsync("/my-account/orders/", content).Result;
}
```

I used tamper to get the headers and this is what I got:

```
wget 
--header="Host: www.gplvault.com" 
--header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" 
--header="Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" 
--header="Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9" 

--header="Cookie: __cfduid=dad983khm234b5jh23s39421e59ce2d1534278105; _ga=GA1.2.1355145636.1534278108; _gid=GA1.2.858287631.1577566529; wordpress_logged_in_13cb68234k56h43k56hk34g22133fe5=some.user%7C1535739391%7CZMz24UN1y2XPWpa1b22yfDi456fdgDGFdfg5jFufjlyKr54%7C68b0b014c9ba2dba566aa0beb44a99f60f97869dFGdfs11125361b3a2e908cd5; wfwaf-authcookie-f227c3e58kjhaf97s98dfasd9081b332=789%7Csubscriber%7Cedbc35748c970a9d4a441209cfc01e5283d791968a1cc28aa740424c08bca223; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; woocommerce_cart_hash=faece8037500a234545305461c8ca026; wp_woocommerce_session_13cb682d9769DFGsdsb449b7722133fe5=789%7C%7C1535739438%7C%7C1535735838%7C%7C7e56398513f91b876s890d4d2f8ccff3b; _gat=1" 

--header="Connection: keep-alive" "https://www.gplvault.com/download/21377/" -O "codecanyon-9899552-actionable-google-analytics-for-woocommerce.zip" -c
```

Comment: I sent my cookies manually using .Add and I was able to find that none of the other cookies except wordpress_logged_in  actually mattered. Is there a way to parse this out and add to the container when I do the POST?